# How to inspect implementation with Scala macros

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-reflect

I'd need to find out if a certain method is used in a method implementation. For example, I have this glorious app:

```
object Test extends App {

    def getGreetings = Array.fill(2)("hello")

    println(getGreetings.mkString("\n"))

}
```

I'd like to test if method `getGreetings` uses the function `fill` of Array's companion object. The test would succeed with the above implementation and fail for example with:

```
def getGreetings = Array("hello", "hello") // nah, fill isn't used
```

With the help of [this video](https://www.parleys.com/tutorial/macros-rest-us) I learned that I can inspect an implementation with macros like this:

```
def printTree(title: String)(expr: Any): Unit = macro printTreeMacro

def printTreeMacro(c: Context)(title: c.Tree)(expr: c.Tree) = {
    import c.universe._

    val code : String = showCode(expr)
    val raw  : String = showRaw(expr)

    q"""
    println(
      $title.toUpperCase + "\n\n" +
      $code              + "\n\n" +
      $raw               + "\n\n"
    )
    """
}

printTree("Method") {
    val a = Array.fill(2)("hello")
}
```

Now `printTree` reveals that the `fill` method is used:

```
Block(List(ValDef(Modifiers(), TermName("a"), TypeTree(),
Apply(Apply(Apply(TypeApply(Select(Select(Ident(scala), scala.Array),
TermName("fill")), List(TypeTree())), List(Literal(Constant(2)))),
List(Literal(Constant("hello")))),
List(Typed(Apply(TypeApply(Select(Ident(scala.reflect.ClassTag),
TermName("apply")), List(TypeTree())),
List(Literal(Constant(String)))), TypeTree()))))), Literal(Constant(())))
```

The missing piece here is how to do the same for the code of any method, so that I could get the tree for what's inside method `getGreetings`.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you mean for any method without changing their body? If so I'm afraid macros won't help much here.

Comment: I'm no expert but I doubt that it's currently possible. Because if that method comes from an imported library, where would the syntax tree come from? All you have then is JVM bytecode (or Scala.js IR, or ...).

Comment: I mean for methods in the current program, i.e. the code I compile. It doesn't have to work for imported libraries (or as pointed out, it cannot). So do I have any other options except for regexing the source code?

Comment: How do you mean "any method". That is, what mechanism to select a method? Easiest is wrapping the body `def f = checker(body)`, but you can also use a macro annotation on the class to check various method bodies, `@checker(method="f, g") class C`.

Comment: Maybe see wartremover or possibly abide. You're talking a lint rule.